# Can I selectively create a backup of Postgres database, with only certian tables?

Tags: database, postgresql, dump, pg-dump

Can I programatically(or whichever way works fine) create the backup of a database, with only the tables I want? I have around 100 tables in my database and I want only 10 tables backup(ofcourse all are interdependant). How can I achieve this? And by the way I have a postgresql database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course. [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/app-pgdump.html) lets you pass list of tables with parameter `-t`

To clear some doubts. True, the `-t` parameter accepts only one pattern. But it's a [pattern](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS) very similar to regular expression, so if you want to dump tables A, B & C you can do:

```
pg_dump -t '(A|B|C)'
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/backup-dump.html, but add the '-t' option (see pg_dump --help).

Comment: I don't think older versions of PostgreSQL allow the '-t' option.

Comment: Actually, I think in 8.0, it allowed only *one* -t option, so you could only dump one table at a time.

Comment: @Paul "the table parameter is interpreted as a pattern according to the same rules used by psql's \d commands"

Comment: is it possible to apply where condition to fetch only selective records in all the 10 tables?