# pg_dump fails with error: `FATAL: role "username" does not exist`

Tags: postgresql

I have a db named `backupdb`, I want to import this to my local rails app so I want to take a dump of it.

When I am running `pg_dump backupdb`, I am getting below error.

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "backupdb" failed: FATAL:  role "username" does not exist

what's wrong here. Please help.

I downloaded the db from my email and then trying to create a dump so I can import it to my local rails app

Comment: Are you sure you use `pg_dump backupdb` not like this `pg_dump dbname > outfile`?

Comment: It does both way I suppose..

Even with this I am getting the same error as question though.

Comment: please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20235049/2750968

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to restore a database. pg_dump is used to dump a database into a file. For restoring, usually you just pipe it to psql command. Some dump formats require pg_restore though. But you aren't specifying any credentials, so it uses the current user. Either add credentials to the command line, or run the command as postgres user.

Answer (score 25):

Try this way, it works!!

```
$ pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -Fc mydb > db.dump
```

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: @Kim it will dump your DB from dump file

Comment: This will only give me `FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`.

Answer (score 4):

This command will take the backup of complete database

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U "dbuser" "dbname" -Fc > "pathfilename.backup"

**ex:** pg_dump -h localhost -U mani manidb - Fc > "thamesdb.backup"
```

for more pg_dump formats please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20235049/2750968) answer

Comment: This is not working, here's what I am trying..

`pg_dump -h localhost -U "postgres" "backupdb" -Fc > "Downloads/backupdb.backup"`

Comment: what is the error you get? and "postgres" "backupdb" should not be in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You're giving "username" as `username`, which does not exist. You need to pass a username that exists (postgres would probably do).
add parameters `--username=postgres --password` and it will ask you for the password for user postgres. (you might have security set to trust in your pg_hba.conf in which case leaving out --password would work.

Comment: as I said, I am just doing this `pg_dump backupdb`

Comment: I run something like `pg_dump ~/backupdb --username=postgres` and I get database doesn't exist.

Comment: your first parameter is databasename, take off the ~/ and try again, post the error.

Comment: It says the same, 

`pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "backupdb" failed: FATAL:  database "backupdb" does not exist
`

Comment: Ok I assume your whole question is backwards. You HAVE a dump and are trying to read it into your DB ?

Comment: no, I have a db, I need a dump of that db so I can import that db dump to my local app.

Comment: You have a db, but when you try to make a dump it doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem but after trying out different permutations of the command options while referencing the documentation, I was able to get it running with this order of options. The command I used is:

```
pg_dump.exe -h localhost -U postgres -t "shop*" -t "core*" -t "profiles*" -f "path/to/output/dir_or_file" mydbname
```

#### Where:

| option prefix | option | params |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -h | host | localhost |
| -U | username | postgres |
| -t | Tables | *Any tables whose name starts with (shop, core, or profiles (NOTE: for django app tables in my case))* |
| -f | file out | *path where I want to save the dumped file* |
| (End of cmd) | database | mydbname |

Note: as I have multiple versions of postgresql on my computer, I had to call the newest pg_dump executable. (Just for reference)

Answer (score 1):

If someone has the same problem using intellij, here is what helped me: 
In my case the Problem was, that i right clicked the datasource, but you have to open it and right click the database itself. So in the image below don't click on localDB. Right click the database name and then do a dump.

Hope this will help someone to solve this confusing UX problem. :D

[image]